# How are local invoices created in laravel spark?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-spark

I have successfully setup spark on my local machine it works perfectly. I have added various plan, which users are able to subscribe by making the payment.
But the invoice section does not show me any invoice which should be created when a user buy's a plan.
Am I missing something?
I mean there is no way to see the previous invoices or receipts which user have already paid for. 
Moreover in DB invoice table is also empty.

[image: Invoice Panel]

Answer (score 5):

To generate invoices in Spark you will need to set up Webhooks for Stripe or Braintree.

---

**Webhooks**

In order to display a list of your customer's invoices, you must configure the appropriate webhooks on *Stripe* or *Braintree*.

*Stripe* webhooks should be configured to point to the `/webhook/stripe` URI. The Braintree `subscription_canceled`, `subscription_charged_successfully`, and `subscription_expired` webhook events should be configured to point to `/webhook/braintree` URI.

---

**Setting up Stripe Endpoints**

1. You can set up your Stripe Webhooks from this url https://dashboard.stripe.com/account/webhooks or by simply logging into the dashboard and clicking *Developer > Webhooks*
2. Create the Endpoint by clicking "+Add Endpoint".
3. Enter in your Endpoint in the *URL to be called* field, for example https://example.com/webhooks/stripe
4. When finished, it should look like this:

[image: endpoints]

> Make sure you are setting web hooks for test and not live!

I use [ngrok](http://ngrok.com) to test my webhooks locally, but if you use Laravel valet you can run `$ valet share`

---

**View Invoices**

After the webhook endpoints are set up, and a user is billed, the invoice will show up properly in the users Settings page under Invoices:

[image]

Comment: I have added the webhook, but still am not able to see the invoices. Where can I look into for investigation?

Comment: Just a note, the example given uses https://example.com/webhooks/stripe when it should be https://example.com/webhook/stripe (in case anyone is trying to paste the snippet).